# Which generic fast collection (set) provides getIndexFromValue or similar?

Tags: c#, collections, set

I need a collection that is a set (no duplicate values) and provides quick insert times. I also need to be able to get the index of a value.

Pseudocode:

```
Set.Insert(value)
Set.GetIndex(value)
```

The position of the value relative to the other values doesn't matter, sorting isn't required.

Is there a C# generic collection that provides this functionality? Or is there a way to do it by combining different collection types?

Comment: What do you want the index for if the relative position is not important?

Comment: Do you need to support removals as well?

Comment: `OrderedDictionary` might work - it's a hash/dictionary - and underneath holds values in an `ArrayList` - with indexed access

Comment: I'm just curious why he needs the index to the internal structure of the Set if the order isn't important. A HashSet would allow 'value' to be it's own 'index'.

Comment: @IlyaIvanov - I know - but there is a source to that - it has an internal method `IndexOfKey` which does just that - i.e. it should be fairly easy to implement that based on OrderedDictionary. Anyways, that 'condition' is a bit questionable - why would the OP need that [index]

Comment: I don't understand why he'd need the index either. He couldn't use it to access the element.

Comment: I need to build an optimized VAO for OpenGL DrawElements. I want to reduce redundancy of the indexed VBOs.

Comment: How will you use the index though? You can't use it to look up the elements in the collection.

Comment: idk opengl that well, but it sounds like a simple dictionary keyed on your vertex with the value of the index of the vertex in an array you are building/built would suit your needs. Just check if your vertex is already in the dictionary before adding it to the vertex list. Then you can use the dictionary to build your index buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `HashSet<T>`  It doesn't allow duplicates and is fast.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx
If you want to get the index of a value, you could convert the `HashSet` into an array and use `Array.IndexOf(value)`; however, the `HashSet` allows you to use the value itself as an index, so you may no longer have need of that.

Comment: This is basically what I need. However, Array.IndexOf is very slow. I am wondering if there is a faster all-in-one solution to it.

Comment: Ok, I will be doing it like this. However, I will use a dictionary along with the array to store the indices, so I get faster lookups.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why is that you'd need to do `id = search[key]` and if this is ideal but i'll just throw it here...

You could try [OrderedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.aspx).

It's not ideal (in terms of your search) - but internally it keeps the method `IndexOfKey` which does just what you need. Basically it's an implementation based on an `ArrayList` which keeps an array of items + you have `Dictionary<>` for fast access etc.

Source is easily found (but I won't link it here for obvious reasons) - and either you can use that - or adjust it.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a wrapper around two Dictionarys

```
class MySet<T> {
    Dictionary<T,int> valToIndex;
    Dictionary<int,T> indexToVal;
    int curIndex;
    Add(T newItem) {
        curIndex++;
        valToIndex.Add(newItem, curIndex);
        indexToVal.Add(curIndex, newItem);
    }
    T this[int index] {
       get {
           return indexToVal[index];
       }
    }
    GetIndexOf(T value) {
        return valToIndex[value];
    }
}
```

Of course this isn't complete, but you get the idea. You will probably want to add more error checking.